# finding words in the proper sequence using regexp

Tags: regex

I'd like to build a regexp that would 
return TRUE if the words `frankie` `goes` and `comes` is found in the haystack in the order above.

Tried this but does not come back with a TRUE.

```
$subject = ' <h1>Frankie goes to hollywood and then comes back </h1>';
$pattern = "/\ Frankie (.*?) goes (.*?) comes (.*?)/";
// this patterns aims to say, find frankie goes and comes in this order with at least one space in between them
$success = preg_match($pattern, $subject);
if ( $success ) :
    echo 'bingo';
endif;
```

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: since I got 0 regexp, done nothing other than trying to see if I can quickly put the reg exp together.  I do not want to spend time trying the understand the regexp cause I rarely need them.

Comment: Well, the Solution is pretty easy.

Comment: *I do not want to spend time trying the understand the regexp*, and then you thought you could post it on SO and use somebody else's time for free. Bravo!

Comment: you got that right! bravo too.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer ( just incase it helps someone )

```
if (preg_match("/[ ]Frankie[ ][\s\S]*goes[ ][\s\S]*comes[ ]/", " Frankie goes to hollywood and then comes back ")) : // OK
    echo '<h1>bingo on FRANKIE .... GOES ....  COMES</h1>';
endif; 

if (preg_match("/[ ]Frankie[ ][\s\S]*comes[ ][\s\S]*goes[ ]/", " Frankie goes to hollywood and then comes back ")) : // OK
else:
    echo '<h1>NO bingo on FRANKIE .... COMES ....  GOES</h1>';
endif;
```